# docker swarm 1.2.0 reschedule with port mapping

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'am testing the brand new version of Docker Swarm 1.2.0 and expecially the rescheduling functionnality.

So, I have one EC2 VM with swarm manager installed and 2 swarm agents (on 2 other EC2 VM). I have an HTTP Rest service I deploy through swarm like this :

```
docker -H :4000 run -d -p :81 -e reschedule:on-node-failure myTestService
```

This command line works fine and deploy my test service on one node (node-1).
If I run a docker ps I see my container deployed on node one :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
23ce231b5737        myTestService               "/nodejs/bin/npm star"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:32768->81/tcp   distracted_sinoussi
```

Look at the port mapping : 0.0.0.0:32768->81/tcp I let docker engine choose an available port on the host (32768).

Now, if I shutdown node-1, swarm should reschedule my container. If I look in the swarm log I have this :

```
time="2016-04-19T13:56:31Z" level=info msg="Initializing discovery without TLS"
time="2016-04-19T13:56:31Z" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP" addr=":4000" proto=tcp
time="2016-04-19T13:56:38Z" level=info msg="Registered Engine ip-node-1 at ip.node.1:2375"
time="2016-04-19T13:56:45Z" level=info msg="Registered Engine ip-node -2 at ip.node.2:2375"
time="2016-04-19T13:58:24Z" level=error msg="Flagging engine as unhealthy. Connect failed 3 times" id="ZSWT:XLYS:D2HA:K5J3:O32D:AFVT:HUNR:ENKI:MBTC:2PVA:JIC2:X74L" name= ip-node-1
time="2016-04-19T13:58:24Z" level=error msg="Error monitoring events: unexpected EOF." id="ZSWT:XLYS:D2HA:K5J3:O32D:AFVT:HUNR:ENKI:MBTC:2PVA:JIC2:X74L" name= ip-node-1
time="2016-04-19T13:58:24Z" level=error msg="Restart event monitoring." id="ZSWT:XLYS:D2HA:K5J3:O32D:AFVT:HUNR:ENKI:MBTC:2PVA:JIC2:X74L" name= ip-node-1
time="2016-04-19T13:58:24Z" level=error msg="Error monitoring events: Get http://ip.node.1:2375/v1.15/events: dial tcp ip.node.1:2375: getsockopt: connection refused." id="ZSWT:XLYS:D2HA:K5J3:O32D:AFVT:HUNR:ENKI:MBTC:2PVA:JIC2:X74L" name=ip-node-1
time="2016-04-19T13:58:24Z" level=info msg="Rescheduled container 23ce231b57375a386909175f3dcd730720429eb4ed41d4366d5add17a30d210e from  ip-node-1 to  ip-node-2 as c7fe68332bc61f0f4c498848e59d3e34b58821468ce65bd4ebc92055156d5b8c"
```

On the last line, we can see that the container has been rescheduled on node-2. Fine, lets do a little docker ps command on node-2 :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c7fe68332bc6        myTestService                nodejs/bin/npm star"      27 seconds ago         Created                                 sleepy_hopper
```

So, the container is there but not running (just "created") and the port mapping is empty.

So what's going wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the expected behaviour. If you safely shutdown the node with something like `shutdown -h now`, the docker daemon running on that node is as well safely stoped. This means, that the last known state to the swarm manager is actually that your containers are stoped and that's why they are not getting started on a new node.

Try to kill the docker daemon on the node with a `kill -9` (like it would actually happen on a true failure). The containers will be rescheduled and will be started on an other node.

Tested with swarm 1.2.1

Comment: Ok... but, if I understand what you say, if the maintenance team has to intervene on the server and reboot it, all containers that are running on it won't be restarted elsewhere after the reschedule. Isn't it too bad?

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the current implementation is like that - [watchdog.go](https://github.com/docker/swarm/blob/master/cluster/watchdog.go#L86) Probably it needs one more label for the reschedule policy or the container should be started if it was initially launched with docker run --restart=always